# Get name of a functions inside a list

Tags: r

**What I wish to achieve**

So I want to get the names of my function inside a list of function.

Here is an example:

```
foo = list(foo1 = sum, foo2 = mean)
```

What I wish to extract from `foo` is:

```
list("sum", "mean")
```

And I would like it to be a function, meaning:

```
> foo = list(foo1 = sum, foo2 = mean)
> super_function(foo)
list("sum", "mean")
```

**What I have checked**

Applying names:

```
> sapply(foo , names)
$`foo1`
NULL

$foo2
NULL
```

Applying deparse(substitute())

```
> my_f <- function(x)deparse(substitute(x))
> sapply(foo, my_f)
    foo1     foo2 
"X[[i]]" "X[[i]]"
```

Neither idea works....

**More background:**

Here are some more details. One don't need them to understand the first question, but are extra details asked by community.

I'm using those functions as aggregation functions given by the user.

```
data(iris)
agg_function<-function(data, fun_to_apply){
  res <- list()
  for (col_to_transform in names(fun_to_apply)){
    res[col_to_transform] <- (fun_to_apply[[col_to_transform]])(data[[col_to_transform]])
  }
  res
}


agg_function(iris, fun_to_apply = list("Sepal.Length" = mean, "Petal.Length" = sum))
```

Result is:

```
$`Sepal.Length`
[1] 5.843333

$Petal.Length
[1] 563.7
```

In this example I'm performing aggregation on two columns of iris. But I wish to have the name of the performed function in the name of each field of my result.
*NB:* This is an over simplification of what I'm doing;

**Conclusion:**

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I thought that. That would have been too easy!

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. Perhaps `my_f1 <- function(x) {lapply(x, deparse)}` could help, although the output of `my_f1(foo)` is not exactly as expected.

Comment: Well, lets take `foo = list(sd)` there is not even a hint in the function code that this is related to "sd". The only thing being the bytecode (how to map the bytecode to a function name) and namespace that limits the amount of candidiates. But consider a function you have in your global envir.

Comment: @rhertel Thanks, I did thought of that bu parsig would be quite ugly to do :/

Comment: Can you give a little bit more background of how you aquire the data (list of funs) and what you want to do with it? Maybe there is a completely different approach to it.

Comment: I edited to add more background

Comment: You need to somehow tell/enforce "the user" to enter the function as a string. Then later you can use it like this: `get("sum")(1:3)`

Comment: Do you mean sth. similar to the output of `library(tidyverse); 
iris %>% 
  summarise_at(vars("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length"), funs("mean", "sum"))`

Comment: @MrFlick mmm I was afraid of that :( Thanks anyway You can post it as an answer if you want.

Comment: @Jimbou, well what I do is really more complicated, I just simplified it to make it understandable. And in my case tidyverse is not usable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are starting from just the list `foo = list(foo1 = sum, foo2 = mean)`, then it's not possible. The call to `list()` will evaluate the parameters returning the values that the variables `sum` and `mean` point to but it will not remember those variable names. Functions don't have names in R. But functions can be assigned to variables. However in R functions can live without names as well.

You've basically just created a named list of function. That might also look like this

```
foo = list(foo1 = function(x) sum(x+1), 
    foo2 = function(x) mean(x+1))
```

Here we also have functions, but these functions don't have "names" other than the names you gave to them in the list.

This only chance you have of making this work is using something other than `list()` when creating foo in the first place. Or having them actually explicitly call `list()` in the function call (which isn't very practical).

Answer (score 0):

Despite you already said that `tidyverse` is not suitable for you, I will add this as an other idea.

```
agg_function <- function(df, x, ...){
 df %>% 
    summarise_at(.vars = x, funs(...))
  }


agg_function(iris, c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length"), mean, sum)  
  Sepal.Length_mean Petal.Length_mean Sepal.Length_sum Petal.Length_sum
1          5.843333             3.758            876.5            563.7
```

Comment: I don't think it really matters if you use tidyverse or not if you have the names of the functions already as character values `c("mean", "sum")`. You could easily do a non-tidyverse version of this function as well with the same input. The problem is that the input data is not a list of character names of functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list with the functions as strings

```
foo <- list(foo1 = "mean", foo2 = "sum")

foo
$foo1
[1] "mean"

$foo2
[1] "sum"

get(foo[[1]])(1:10)
[1] 5.5
get(foo[[2]])(1:10)
[1] 55
```

Or use the `rlang` package and do something like

```
library(rlang)
foo <- quos(foo1 = mean, foo2 = sum)

getNames <- function(x) {
+   sapply(x, function(x) x[[2]])
+ }

getNames(foo)
$foo1
mean

$foo2
sum

eval_tidy(foo[[1]])(1:10)
[1] 5.5
eval_tidy(foo[[2]])(1:10)
[1] 55
```

This also works with non named functions

```
foo <- quos(foo1 = function(x) sum(x + 1), foo2 = sum)
getNames(foo)
$foo1
function(x) sum(x + 1)

$foo2
sum

eval_tidy(foo[[1]])(1:10)
[1] 65
```