# How can I distinguish `alist` from `list` in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to pass functions into another function for evaluation. I want to preserve the name of the function as I will use it in naming the output. In the MWE below, I just print the name. I can do this if I pass in my function(s) as an `alist` but not as a `list`.

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:3)
foo <- function(df, a, i) {
  # Insert a check along the lines of is.alist(a) here
  print(paste('Applying', a[[i]], 'to the dataframe df'))
  result <- eval(a[[i]])(df)
  return(result)
}

a <- alist(min, sum)
foo(df, a, 2)

l <- list(min,sum)
foo(df, l, 2)
```

This gives the following output

```
> a <- alist(min, sum)
> foo(df, a, 2)
[1] "Applying sum to the dataframe df"
[1] 6
> 
> l <- list(min,sum)
> foo(df, l, 2)
 Error in paste("Apply", a[[i]], "to the dataframe df") : 
  cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'
```

I'd like to check inside foo and report back to the user that they should pass then functions in `alist` instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: If a named list were required then names(a)[i] could be used in the print statement.

Comment: thanks. I want them to pass a list of functions and I don't think functions have a 'name' when passed in a list

Comment: A named list is something like this `L <- list(min = min, sum = sum)` .  Now you can refer to `names(L) `to get the names.  Another thing you could do is have them pass a character vector of function names.  `nams <- c("min", "sum")`  In which case `nams` gives the names and `lapply(nams, match.fun)` gives the functions.

Answer (score 2):

`alist` does not evaluate, `list` does. They are not the same. If you want to use `list` anyway, you'd have to quote:

```
l <- list(quote(min) ,quote(sum))
foo(df, l, 2)

[1] "Applying sum to the dataframe df"
[1] 6
```

Comment: That's my point. I need the user to pass an `alist` and I want to check they have done that. I can't use `class(a)` because that returns `list` regardless of the input being an `alist` or a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

`alist` returns a list:

```
identical(alist(min, sum), 
          list(quote(min), quote(sum)))
#[1] TRUE
```

You can't test how a list has been created. You could test the type of the list elements:

```
vapply(a, typeof, FUN.VALUE = "")
#[1] "symbol" "symbol" 

vapply(l, typeof, FUN.VALUE = "")
#[1] "builtin" "builtin"
```

But let me recommend redesigning your function. I don't think it is good practice to require users to use `alist`.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect then I need a separate question but I struggled to find a way to pass a function and not lose its name. I'd found this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51634713/992999) but `alist` seemed like an alternative to try.