Evaluate a list in a function while keeping its values as symbols
I have a function that can take a list in one of its arguments. I would like to be able to manipulate this list in the function but without having the elements of the list evaluated.
For example, if I have this:
external <- list("a" = mean, "foo" = sum)

foo <- function(x) {
  rlang::get_expr(x)
}

Then when I call foo(external), I'd like to have an object that I can manipulate inside foo() like:
$a
mean

$foo
sum

where mean and sum are symbols. So far, I have that:
foo(external)
#> $a
#> function (x, ...) 
#> UseMethod("mean")
#> <bytecode: 0x58773e2c7020>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
#> 
#> $foo
#> function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")

but that isn't what I'd like to have since the functions in the list are evaluated.
Is this possible? I'm ok with base or rlang solutions.

If you use expressions as input, you will get expected output : external <- list("a" = expr(mean), "foo" = expr(sum))

Yeah but I don't control what is put in the input list

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51637040/13513328

@Waldi well that's almost the same question as mine and the answers there are helpful, closing as duplicate, thank you :) EDIT: actually can't close myself, but others can vote to close too
